# css flex column prevent child elements stretch from each other's content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

im trying to reach into a point that the elements inside #container id wont effect each other's width, i want .a(class) to have his green background only around the content and to prevent growing because of his siblings content.

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    a
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="a">a</div> <-- this elements grows in width (see green background in the playground)
    <div class="b">wwww</div> <- as this element has more content
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.a {
  background: green;
}
.b {
  background: yellow;
}
```

play ground:
https://jsfiddle.net/qdb51ce3/

thanks.

Comment: align-self: flex-start; to .a ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do this

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="a"><span>b</span></div>
    <div class="b"><span>wwww</span></div>
</div>
```

and style you background or anything else on the child `span` rather than the flexed `.a`

```
.a span{
  background: green;
}
```

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bv65ch9u/1/)

Comment: I think this approach would be more reasonable. You should avoid text directly in <div>. Use <p> or <h> according to your needs. It will make the difference with SEO and accesibility:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/HTML